# React native props to parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

To start i am sorry i am a new on native react

I have a project with react navigation who show this component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {FlatList,StyleSheet,View,TouchableHighlight,Text} from 'react-native'
import {
  Container,
  Button,
  ListItem,
  Left,
  Right,
  Icon,
  Body
} from 'native-base';
import Customer from '../Customer';
import Search from '../../../components/Search'


export default class SearchCustomer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      customerList:[]
    }
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <Customer>
        <Search
          setCustomerList = {(customerList) => {this.setState({customerList})}}
        />
        <FlatList
            data={this.state.customerList}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            renderItem={({ item, index}) => (
              <ListItem onPress={(item) => this.props.callback()}>
                <Left style={styles.left}>
                    <Text>{item.firstname} {item.lastname}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{item.email}</Text>
                </Left>
                <Right>
                  <Icon name='arrow-forward' />
                </Right>
              </ListItem>
        )}/>
      </Customer>
    )
  }
}
```

This component call his parent that here below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Container,
  Button,
  Text,
} from 'native-base';
import Order from '../Order';

export default class Customer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Order>
        {this.props.children}
      </Order>
    )
  }
}
```

I want to know how can i send data from the child to his parent with this configuration.

Currently i am trying to catch `this.props.callback()` in the parent but i can't use this `callback={() => {console.log('Ok')}}`

I have this error

[image: error onPress call]

Someone have a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some of your class you can define a method in your parent class then pass the function as props to child

```
export default class Customer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    }
  }

  callback = (data) => { console.log(data) } 

  render() {
    return (
      <Order callback={this.callback}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Order>
    )
  }
}
```

Then from child you can provide the data in the callback for parent.

```
export default class Order extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.callback('hi')}>
        <Text>Click Me!</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity >
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You change the class SearchCustomer for Order, in my exemple Order is the parent of the Customer class and Customer is call on SearchCustomer.
Your example works, but that's not at all my current problem

Comment: Using this.props.callback inside searchCustomer component means that you have the callback function as prop to searchCustomer. I just provided a follow in which you can pass data back to parent component's function ..

Answer (score 0):

read this for more good understanding : https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#passing-data-through-props

Comment: This tutorial was great but i don't see a callback data on component load by `this.props.children`